# TypeError: data is undefined when using datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to retrieve data from the server using DataTables.I can view the json response in the network section of my browser as well.But in the console it gives me **TypeError: data is undefined**. Nothing shows inside the table except column names and **Processing..** label.

> Here is my Json response:

```
{"userList":[{"age":23,"userId":123,"user_name":"Mike"},{"age":22,"userId":345,"user_name":"John"},{"age":23,"userId":123,"user_name":"Peter"}]}
```

[json response img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdGjo.png)

> Java Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#mytable').dataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": "jsond",
                    "columns": [
                        {"userList": "userId"},
                        {"userList": "user_name"},
                        {"userList": "age"}
                    ]
                });
            });
```

> Html:

```
<table id="mytable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
```

Can somebody suggest me a way to get rid of this error please ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to this page your data format is wrong.

[Ajax sourced data](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

```
{ 
    "data":[{"age":23,"userId":123,"user_name":"Mike"},{"age":22,"userId":345,"user_name":"John"},{"age":23,"userId":123,"user_name":"Peter"}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the mistake.:)